# onClick() -> Loading / onSuccess -> addClass or removeClass (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, onclick

I have an issue that look simple but I can not solve.

I am developing a code that, when the users click on "span", the code add class if it is not check or remove class if it is checked.

```
<!-- This is the span -->

<span class="label label-<?=$tag?><?=$selected?" selected":" hidden-print"?> customer-<?=$i?>" onclick="connect('customer-<?=$i?>', '<?=$customer?>', '<?=$tag?>');"><?=$tag?></span><?
```

```
<script>
    function connect(customerId, customerValue, tagValue) {
        var label = $("span.label-" + tagValue + "." + customerId);
        var connectar = !label.hasClass('selected');
        console.log("haciendo " + connectar + " la conexión entre " + customerValue + " y " + tagValue);
        $.getJSON("/api/connect.php?customerId=" + customerValue + "&tagId=" + tagValue + "&connect=" + connectar, function(data) {
            console.log('error: ' + data.error);
            if (data.error == "false") {
                if (data.connected == "true") {
                    label.addClass("selected");
                    label.removeClass("hidden-print");
                }
                if (data.connected == "false") {
                    label.removeClass("selected");
                    label.addClass("hidden-print");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I want a new javascript code to show a  "Loading..." text or gif in onClick case (Something simple) and addClass or removeClass onSuccess case.

Actually looks like this:

**Clicked, loading, success**

http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/478/vgl5.png

I want will look like this:

**Loading Phase**

http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/9230/c4sc.png

Best regards.

Comment: What is the problem? What is containing the arguments `customerId, customerValue, tagValue`?

Comment: The problem is that I dont have a code for show and hide a loading text for onclick and onsuccess case. Those arguments are data that I need for the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing the "loading..." you can use `.ajaxStart()` and for hiding you can use `.ajaxComplete()`:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('.loading').show();
}).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('.loading').hide();
});
```

assuming that you should have a loading gif image or loading text in your element `.loading`.

Comment: I dont have a gif or text. Where have I to put the text? And where I have to put this code ajaxStart and ajaxComplete in the script?